# How can I get SQL COUNT's with different conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display some statistics to users that entered a command and I'm using to different SQL queries for that.

The first one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM guild_finished_giveaways WHERE guild_id = {} AND winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%'
```

I want to get the giveaway win count from this specific user on the specified guild.

But in the second query, I want the same, except for the specified guild. It should count all entries, like a "global" giveaway win count.

The second one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM guild_finished_giveaways winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%'
```

How can I combine them into only run one query? I need this solution to improve my code performance and reduce code.

Comment: what does winner_id look like?  it will be much more efficient if you are matching a prefix of the column value and it is index, or you have an indexed virtual column with the guild id if it needs to be extracted from json or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUM() instead.

```
SELECT SUM(guild_id = {} AND winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%') as guild_winer ,
       SUM(winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%') as win_sum
FROM guild_finished_giveaways ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN guild_id = {} THEN 1 END) AS count_id,
       COUNT(*) AS count_all
FROM guild_finished_giveaways 
WHERE winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%';
```

or:

```
SELECT SUM(guild_id = {}) AS count_id,
       COUNT(*) AS count_all
FROM guild_finished_giveaways 
WHERE winner_id LIKE '%750718563651944518%';
```